# Localdb with the Configuration " MultipleActiveResultSets = True"

Tags: sql-server, localdb

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to enable the MultipleActiveResultSets = True command on the sql server localdb.

I'm having problems with DataReader opened in the same method, even closing the connection.

My connection string:   caminho =

```
$"Data Source = (LocalDB)\\v11.0; AttachDbFilename = { MDF}; Integrated Security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. We use this in dozens of production sites. We found it absolutely necessary in order to use EntityFramework. What is the specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: So, I had this doubt, because the localdb is mono user, but in fact I have not received any errors. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. We use LocalDB with MultipleActiveResultSets (MARS) enabled in our application at dozens of sites, both test and production. In fact, we found it absolutely **necessary** to enable MARS in order to successfully use Entity Framework.